# Problem starting bkcrack from a terminal

Tags: command-line, password, pdf, password-recovery, zip

First, I will describe how I use bkcrack:

I am using LINUX in the live version (Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS). I downloaded the LINUX version of bkcrack from GITHUB and put the password file in this folder (bkcrack). Then I right clicked on the main bkcrack folder and chose the "open in terminal" option and typed the commands.

I would like to crack a password in a .zip file I created a few years ago and forgot my password. The compression algorithm is ZipCrypto Deflate.

There is only one file in MYFILE.zip - ABCD.pdf. I have an older copy of this PDF that is identical to the one that has a password of about 90%.

I tried to use BKCRACK. I opened the MYFILE.zip file in the HxD program and saw the header of the zip file in HEX format (50 4B 03 04) and the name ABCD.pdf in HEX format (41 42 43 44 2E 70 64 66) - offset 30. Thanks to this I have 12 bytes known text.

Then I used the command:

```
echo -n "ABCD.pdf" > plain.txt

time bkcrack -C MYFILE.zip -c ABCD.pdf -p plain.txt -o 30 -x 0 504B0304 > 1.log & tail -f 1.log
```

Unfortunately the result is:

[1] 5849

```
bkcrack: command not found

real 0m0.220s

user 0m0.078s

sys 0m0.041s
```

Please help, am I doing something wrong? How do I run bkcrack on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `time ./bkcrack -C MYFILE.zip -c ABCD.pdf -p plain.txt -o 30 -x 0 504B0304 > 1.log & tail -f 1.log` to tell `bash` you want to use the program `bkcrack` in the current directory `./` or use the entire path to it in the command. The directory you are in is not in the `PATH` for `bash` to find it.

Comment: I used ./bkcrack unfortunately it got the following message:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/sam-zip$ echo -n "ABCD.pdf" > plain.txt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/sam-zip$ time ./bkcrack -C MYFILE.zip -c ABCD.pdf -p plain.txt -o 30 -x 0 504B0304 > 1.log & tail -f 1.log
[1] 6505
bash: line 2: ./bkcrack: Permission denied

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.001s

Comment: So I used additionally: sudo -s but that didn't help either:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/sam-zip$ sudo -s
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/sam-zip# echo -n "ABCD.pdf" > plain.txt
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/sam-zip# time ./bkcrack -C MYFILE.zip -c ABCD.pdf -p plain.txt -o 30 -x 0 504B0304 > 1.log & tail -f 1.log
[1] 6704
/bin/bash: line 2: ./bkcrack: Permission denied

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.000s

Comment: No clue if it will not allow root to do it, it is impossible to get it done it is the account that is all powerful and should not have permission errors. One thought now it occurs to me, have you used `chmod +x /path/to/bkcrack`? To make sure it is executable, only thing I can think of that could be wrong.